# Asp.net core 6 app not reflecting markup changes on cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a blog that is built on razor engine with asp.net core 6

Locally my markup changes work fine but not on the server.

Something is wrong. Am I missing a runtime compilation or something?

Comment: Hi, What is markup changes?

Comment: I have changed logic on my cshtml file for example an if statement is removed and the changes dont reflect on the server after uploading the changed files

Comment: Hi, try to enable runtime compilation, refer to :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The App reflects the changes locally but not on the server

Comment: @ Rena. I have already tried that